# using System.Data.Entity.Database; in MVC 3.0 is not working in Mvc Music Store

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi i am new in MVC and i am following a course link "https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mvcmusicstore" and i am having a problem with `using System.Data.Entity.Database;`, it says An instance of this class is obtained from an System.Data.Entity.Dbcontext object and can be used to manage the actual database backing a DBContext or connection, i downloaded the latest version of EntityFramework 6.2.0 and what i am trying to do is to show the data that is in a class in the model named SampleData but i am stuck at the `using System.Data.Entity.Database;` ERROR

Please Help And Thank You For It :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to follow a course that has been kept up to date? MVC3 is almost 8 years old. Things have moved on.

Comment: i know, but i am a friend suggested me that course

Comment: Show your context. You should not need `using System.Data.Entity.Database;` - `using System.Data.Entity;` should be sufficient.

Comment: While it is a good tutorial, it is dated and at the very least you'd need to be more aware of the dependency versions you install. Entity Framework in particular has changed quite a bit. At the very least determine the version of EF that tutorial targets and use that instead of the latest EF version. This more recent tutorial covers much of the same content https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/. And even that tutorial is superseded by ASP.NET Core MVC tutorials.

Comment: Mr @SteveGreene, it has been solved with your changing but another problem appeared when running the project, in 'var genres = storeDB.Genre.ToList();' , it says An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'

Comment: That is a basic configuration problem. Looks like your provider is pointing at SQL CE. Easiest thing might be to uninstall EF, remove all references from web.config and then reinstall.

Comment: @SteveGreene, Thank You for your help, it is configuration problem